# Pass parameter to href of a table cell in ajax

Tags: html, ajax, parameter-passing

I'm new to use ASP.net for web app programming. I'm using the following ajax function aiming to send a parameter to the controller with the name of yyy. However, no matter how I manipulate the variable {id} in this case, the controller either get the string {id} or null. The variable of {id} is actually storing an integer value, for example, 3. I want to pass the integer 3 to the controller. Please help! Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8086/xxx",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var testData = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                testData += '<tr>';                    
                var id = value.testDataID.toString();
                testData += '<td style="cursor:pointer">' + '<a href="http://localhost:8087/xxx/yyy?param="+{id}>' + value.serialNumber + '</a>' + '</td>';
                testData += '<td>' + value.testDataID + '</td>';
                    testData += '<td>' + value.sN + '</td>';
                    testData += '</tr>';
                });
            $('#testDataTable').append(testData);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Assuming `id` is a variable with a value: `testData += '<td style="cursor:pointer">' + '<a href="http://localhost:8087/xxx/yyy?param="' + id + "'>' + value.serialNumber + '</a>' + '</td>';` Right now you are sending the string `"+{id}` to the controller.

Comment: Correct. That's exactly what I want to solve. id is retrieved from data base, so it's a "dynamic" integer. What i want is to send the integer stored in id to the controller.